# R lines / segments overlaid on contourplot rendering incorrectly?

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have some r code that produces a filled contour plot or a function that takes either 0 or 1, and then I want to overlay some lines on it. But I'm getting some strange behaviour with the lines produced, whether I use lines or segments, namely that the lines always appear markedly longer than they should be. The relevant code section is as follows:

```
xc = 16.71
yc = 10.51
colorsforplot <- c("lightgreen", "white")
filled.contour(xgrid, ygrid, zres, nlevels = 2, col = colorsforplot, xlim = c(0, 1.03*xc), ylim = c(0, 1.03*yc))

lyv <- segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, x1 = 0, y1 = yc, col = "darkgreen", lty = "dashed", lwd = 2)
lyx <- segments(x0 = 0,y0 = 0,x1 = xc, y1 = 0, col = "blue", lty = "dashed", lwd = 2)
```

The result I get is this, which is clearly wrong. Any ideas what might be happening? I've trying setting aspect ratios equal, but the behaviour remains.

[image]

Comment: Hi DRG! Could you please share a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? What is xgrid? And ygrid?